# Complex integral along a contour on which the function is zero, but include poles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

While trying to solve this integral
$$
I=\int_{-a}^{a}dx\frac{e^{-i\omega x}e^{-x^2/4b^2}}{(x-i\epsilon)^2}Erf(a-|x|)~,
$$
I found something that seems a contradiction. I am clearly missing something, but cannot figure out what.

Specifically, since $Erf(0)=0$ one can extend the integrand to the complex plane, evaluate the integral on the contour made by glueing the segment $[-a,a]$ to the half circle of radius $a$ (either in the upper plane), and use Cauchy's theorem to argue that the contour integral solves to $2\pi i$ times the residue in $x=i\epsilon$. Then, since on the half circle the function is identically zero, one gets
$$
I=2\pi i~\lim_{z\to i\epsilon}\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{-i\omega x}e^{-x^2/4b^2}Erf(a-|x|)\right)~,
$$
which is some finite number. All is good up to now!

However, if one now takes the contour to be the full circle finds that zero (i.e. the result of integrating a function along a contour on which it evaluates to zero identically) is equal to $I$, i.e. a finite number.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Conrad Yeah, but integrating on the circle would give zero identically, while by Cauchy's theorem it would be I (not talking about evaluating I itself now). Hence, there seems to be a contradiction in which $0=I$, while $I\neq 0$!

Comment: Actually, I was a bit hasty in my comment - the issue is that the function is not analytic inside the circle as it contains that $|z|$ so you actually cannot apply Cauchy (this is like applying Cauchy for $\frac{1-|z|}{z}$ which gives you zero on the circle but would have a "pole" at zero - of course the problem is that the function is not (complex) analytic

Comment: I see... I was actually thinking something similar, but it seemed that the function was analytic to me (as a check, I also plotted it in Mathematica, and it looks pretty smooth :) )! Do you know how I could see that it is not analytic? Also, any idea on how to solve the integral instead?

Comment: it is real analytic of course so it is smooth - the $|z|$ shows that the function is not complex analytic as $|z|^2=z \bar z$ so the function depends essentially on $\bar z$ and complex analytic functions must be constant in $\bar z$ so depend only on $z$ (this is of course not quite rigorous talk but it should be intuitive)

Comment: anyway since the original integral is real, why not replace $|x|$ with $\pm x$ and then move to the complex plane where at least for large $a$ you may be able to at least estimate the integral on the half circle where $x=ae^{i\theta}$

Comment: Ok I can see now the non analyticity and how it prevents the contour on the circle.... Maybe integrating on a contour inside the circle would do the job. About extending to infinity, the thing is I need it to stay finite but yes, you can find a solution for infinite a